# Can VBA Forms have a Flow Layout?

Tags: winforms, ms-access, vba, layout

I'm guessing this is impossible, but here goes.

Java and more recent .Net updates are capable of a Flow Layout - where a layout manager re-arranges the form controls to fit in the available space.

I've only seen VBA & WinForms using hard-coded absolute positions.

Has anyone encountered a flow-layout manager in this context?

Answer (score 3):

Access 2007 and later versions implement this functionality via anchoring: [Make controls stretch, shrink, or move as you resize a form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-controls-stretch-shrink-or-move-as-you-resize-a-form-HA010253986.aspx)

If you want to do it in earlier versions you can roll your own using the On Resize event of the form.

Comment: Aah, that's a new feature for me to look out for, thanks.  Now, I wonder when my client will "leap forward" and adopt Access 2007 ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I have a form which is laid out like this.  All of my controls are sequentially named based on their vertical position:  txt_R1, txt_R2, txt_R3 etc...

[image: Form Design]

When the Form loads, it looks like this:

[image: Form Loaded]

When I update the combo box, the code below executes:

```
Dim s_tier As String
Dim s_rate As String
Dim s_lbl_Rate As String
Dim s_lbl_Tier As String
Dim s_obj As String

Me.TXT_Min.Visible = True
Me.LBL_MIN.Visible = True
Me.TXT_Min.Value = 0

Me.TXT_Scale.Visible = True
Me.lbl_Scale.Visible = True
Me.TXT_Scale.Value = 0

Me.txt_MinMax.Visible = True
Me.lbl_MinMax.Visible = True
Me.txt_MinMax.Value = 0

s_tier = "TXT_T"
s_rate = "TXT_R"
s_lbl_Rate = "LBL_R"
s_lbl_Tier = "LBL_T"

For i = 1 To numActive
    
    'Tier Text Box
    s_obj = s_tier & i
    
    Me(s_obj).Visible = True
    Me(s_obj).Value = "NULL"
    
    'Tier Label
    s_obj = s_lbl_Tier & i
    
    Me(s_obj).Visible = True
                            
    'Rate Text Box
    s_obj = s_rate & i
    
    Me(s_obj).Visible = True
    Me(s_obj).Value = "NULL"
    
    'Rate Label
    s_obj = s_lbl_Rate & i
    
    Me(s_obj).Visible = True

Next i

'set last tier to infinite, since last tier typically goes on forever
s_obj = s_tier & numActive

Me(s_obj).Value = ChrW(&H221E)
Me(s_obj).FontSize = 16

'Make Test button visible and move to appropriate place

s_obj = s_lbl_Tier & (numActive + 1)

Me.Btn_Test.Top = Me(s_obj).Top
Me.Btn_Test.Left = Me(s_obj).Left
Me.Btn_Test.Visible = True

s_obj = s_tier & (numActive + 1)
'Make Test button visible and move to appropriate place
    
Me.btn_SQL.Top = Me(s_obj).Top
Me.btn_SQL.Left = Me(s_obj).Left
Me.btn_SQL.Visible = True
Me.Refresh
```

The refreshed form now looks like this if "1" is selected in the combo box:
[image: Choose an option]

... Or if "2" is selected in the combo box:
[image: Choose an option]

... Or if "3" is selected in the combo box:
[image: Choose an option]

The key to my method is to use the sequential naming convention as a way to exploit the

```
for i = 1 to numactive
```

piece of code.  Once the loop ends, all of the static controls are visible.  I can add 1 the numactive variable to determine where the first invisible control is, and anchor my 'floating' controls to that position.

This method can be tweaked to actually place any control into any position using offsets instead of the position of other controls.  Let your imagination run wild!

Answer (score 1):

WinForms of course has the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) and [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)..

There's an [example of AutoLayout for Winforms on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/permanenttan/archive/2006/03/07/545445.aspx).

Comment: I appreciated that it was possible in .Net - though it only appears to be used rarely.  But do you know of a VBA solution?